# Regular Expression for TextInput component: MM/DD/YY

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm terrible with Regular Expressions but I believe in this case I must create one.

Basically, a user needs to type a date of format: MM/DD/YYYY into a TextInput and I need to verify it.

Can anyone point me in the direction of those old Flex regular expression testers that I can no longer find, please?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here's the regular expression just in case it'll help someone:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d$/;
```

Comment: Like [this one](http://www.stratulat.com/Regular_Expressions_Flex.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grant Skinner has regexer, I think thet's what you are looking for
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

regexpal is pretty decent too
http://regexpal.com/

`\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}`  for DD/DD/DDDD
`\d\d?/\d\d?/\d{4}`  for D/D/DDDD and DD/DD/DDDD

Comment: Thank you both. I've updated my original post with the Regular Expression itself.

Comment: ah yes, that one is quite a bit more strict in therms of date range.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using regular expressions (which are perfectly fine, they can just get messy), you might consider using the Flex [DateValidator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/validators/DateValidator.html) or a Flex 3 [DateField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html) control. Both of these methods will make sure you end up with a valid input with little effort on your part.

There is an example of how to use each class found at the bottom of the pages I linked to.

Comment: I actually did check into that at first but, from what I read, it seemed that I can get more precise validation using regular expressions.

Comment: On second thought, I'm going to look into the DateValidator idea. The regular expression I have above forces me to use a zero before a month with only 1 number, I.e. Jan, Feb, etc.. I did initially go with the DateField component but it got shot down by the man in charge.

Comment: Ok Sunil, I ended up going with your approach and it's a lot cleaner and easier. Thank you!